# Convert eastern arabic numerals to western arabic in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a problem where a eastern-arabic numeral has entered my table as a timestamp and bigquery doesn't recognise this as a timestamp and will not execute my queries.

I wish to be able to convert this:

'٢٠١٨-١٠-١١T١٦:٠١:٤١.٠٤١Z'

into this:

'2018-10-11T16:01:41.041Z

in bigquery, Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this SQL UDF:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION arabicConvert(input STRING) AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(COALESCE(FORMAT('%i', i), letter), '')
  FROM (SELECT SPLIT(input, '') x), UNNEST(x) letter
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT letter_dict,i FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT('٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩', '') l), UNNEST(l) letter_dict WITH OFFSET i
  )
  ON letter=letter_dict
));

SELECT arabicConvert('٢٠١٨-١٠-١١T١٦:٠١:٤١.٠٤١Z') converted


2018-10-11T16:01:41.041Z
```

Answer (score 1):

There is alternative, lighter option :o)

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION arabicNumeralsConvert(input STRING) AS ((
    CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
      SELECT IF(code > 1600, code - 1584, code) 
        FROM UNNEST(TO_CODE_POINTS(input)) code
    )) 
)); 
WITH t AS (
    SELECT '٢٠١٨-١٠-١١T١٦:٠١:٤١.٠٤١Z' str UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-10-12T20:34:57.546Z'
)
SELECT str, arabicNumeralsConvert(str) converted
FROM t
```

result is as

```html
str                          converted
٢٠١٨-١٠-١١T١٦:٠١:٤١.٠٤١Z    2018-10-11T16:01:41.041Z
2018-10-12T20:34:57.546Z     2018-10-12T20:34:57.546Z
```